# Optimise MySQL query with subqueries

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to optimize this query? Is it possible to generate an index? Without optimization it takes 8s.

```
SELECT
    partner_banner_views AS views,
    (
      SELECT
        count(statistics_partner_id)
      FROM
        statistics_partner
      WHERE
        statistics_partner_partner_id = partner_id
      AND statistics_partner_click_date IS NOT NULL
    ) AS clicks,
    round (
    (
        100 *(
            SELECT
                count(statistics_partner_id)
            FROM
                statistics_partner
            WHERE
                statistics_partner_partner_id = partner_id
            AND statistics_partner_click_date IS NOT NULL
        )/ partner_banner_views
    ),
    3
) AS ctr
FROM partners
```

THX

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks information to diagnose the problem. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an index on `statistics_partner_partner_id` or `statistics_partner_partner_id,statistics_partner_click_date` if you expect to have a lot of `NULL` click dates.

You can convert it to a `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT
    partner_banner_views AS views,
    COUNT(statistics_partner_partner_id) as clicks,
    ROUND(100 * clicks / COUNT(statistics_partner_partner_id), 3) as ctr
FROM partners
LEFT JOIN statistics_partner ON statistics_partner_partner_id = partner_id 
                                AND statistics_partner_click_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY partner_id
```